# Spectrophotometry: shifting absorbance curves vertically so isosbestic points match

Tags: analytical-chemistry, spectrophotometry

We're measuring reaction kinetic parameters of a hydration reaction (Co complex) by measuring the absorption spectrum a different time intervals, and calculating the ratio of product to reactant by comparing the absorbance measured to the absorbance spectrums of the product and reactant in pure form. Water baths at 6 different temperatures were tested and for certain graphs, the results are coherent, with curves meeting around the isosbestic point (where the absorbance of both product and reactant are the same, first graph). However for certain graphs there is a significant vertical shift on certain curves which renders the results incoherent (second graph)

I had the idea to shift the stray curves down to match the isosbestic points of the product and reactant, as this should technically be constant whatever the reaction progression (at a given concentration). I realize this will render the use of the Beer-Lambert law pointless as we are completely fabricating our results, however what is important is the ratio of product and reactant, relative to other curves, which will be conserved, and these will actually be comparable once the isosbestic points match.

I just wanted some outside input

-Is this unscientific? Will my TA wonder what the hell i've done and take points off, or is this process justifiable

-Should i just process and present my data without trying to correct the error.

-What could this baseline error be caused by? since the errored curves seem to be shifted up, i'm suspecting condensation on the cuvette walls increased the absorbance, as the water baths went up to 50 degree. Although I dont remember noticing condensation on the cuvettes.

Thank you for any input.

[image: Good Plot]
[image: Wild plot where things whent wrong]

Comment: For clarification: Is the instrument a dispersive one (reference and sample cell measured simultaneously)?  Just a couple of weeks ago, there was a similar question about overcompensating a baseline, and fluctations in the light source's intensity over time -- which a dispersive instrument may easier compensate than a single beam instrument -- was one possible cause. (https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/128248/why-is-absorbance-in-uv-vis-spectrometer-negative-even-after-calibration/128251#128251)

Comment: thank you for the link, the instrument was in fact dispersive. The reference solution was not changed throughout the measurements,

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? For example, how many water baths were used to get the 8 curves in the bottom figure? In the upper figure (at room temperature?), only the yellow curve is offset a small amount. But the bottom figure has rather large jumps: 0 min curve high, next three low, rest high again. Were these all collected by you or were lab partners involved?

Comment: @EdV An evidence against working within the same lab group could be that the the ratio of Abs for t = 0 around  460 and 620 nm are both about 1.3, but the absolute ABS values recorded for this time do not equate to each other.  Otherwise, the first plot _(except the yellow trace) would be fine.

Comment: It's very hard to be precise, but I would not expect condensation at the  higher temperatures, more likely here is that small bubbles form on inside of the cell wall that come and go with time. Unless you can repeat all you can do is to use the isobestic points from the top graph to correct the lower one, always remembering in your report you _must_ describe why you had to do this.

Comment: @ibsrewed Was the reference cell filled with the blank solvent?  You ensured both sample and reference at the same temperature, correct? Was the direction of the cells always the same -- sometimes using the cell with the pathway mark facing the lamp does not yield the same readout as using the cell with the pathway mark facing the detector (plastic cells more than the ones of quartz, but likely you used always the same sample cell, didn't you?).

Comment: @Buttonwood Yeah, good point! I would like to see the lab write up given to the students, and literature reference(s), but, lacking that, it could just be operator error(s) or the bubbles mentioned by porphyin!

Comment: @ibsrewed _I speculate_ the conditions for the second plot are such that the reaction run about six times as fast to completion, than for the first plot.  With the old rule of thumb that per 10...15 K temperature increase the reaction rate would double, are the time readings converted to minutes, but based on seconds? Recalling my TAing, the most accurate students for recording UV kinetic data had several dry runs to learn who would _consistently_ need the same time between taking the sample, putting the cell into the UV / closing lid and hitting _the_ button within $\pm 5\,\pu{s}$ per cycle.

Comment: @ibsrewed In this perspective, _perhaps_ something delayed the anticipated line of events; e.g. once there were droplets on the wall of the cell, but there wasn't a tissue to dry the cell, hence delaying putting the sample into the slot, thumbling to get the file name into the software, etc. pp. You need to have practise rounds (almost drill-like) _especially_ if you collect the data manually; without chatty disturbance from / with other colleagues or the TA until all data for one of these plots is recorded. And plot these plots early (e.g., graph paper) to see the problem early, in the lab.

Comment: thank you for your input. each graph shows the evolution of absorbance spectrum at the given time intervals at a specific temperature. sorry I didn't add the actual captions. The methodology for each measurement was relatively straight forward, extracting a given volume by pipette, placing into cuvette and usually within a minute the spectrometer measurements started, each lasting about 1.5 minutes. Multiple reactions were going on at the same time, a few times we had a "queue" of 2 cuvettes however this should not change the fact that the curves should go through isosbestic point.

Comment: this would just affect the accuracy of the kinetic parameters, since the reaction kept proceeding in the cuvette, although it was relatively slow at room temperature. The first plot was at 35degC, the second at 50degC. We cant say for sure whether the temp of the reference solvent cuvette and sample cuvette were the same however given the size of the cuvette I would have assumed it would cool relatively quickly.

Comment: anyway we'll proceed to calibrating the curves around the isosbestic point, i've only to decide which one, the right or the left, or do an average shift around the two. We'll play around and see which gives the nicest results. also the cuvettes used were just as translucent in both directions (no corrugated sides like ive seen some are) and we were careful not to leave fingerprints so they were always held on the top.